# Defining loop for discrete values in Python

Tags: python, numpy

The code deletes multiples sets of rows and columns. Is it possible to define a loop with discrete values, here `2,4,8` instead of writing `mask[2] = 0, mask[4] = 0, mask[8] = 0`?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1,101).reshape(10,10)
#print([x])

mask = np.ones(x.shape[0], bool)

mask[2] = 0
mask[4] = 0
mask[8] = 0

print([x[mask,:][:,mask]])
```

The current and desired output should be the same which is

```
[array([[  1,   2,   4,   6,   7,   8,  10],
       [ 11,  12,  14,  16,  17,  18,  20],
       [ 31,  32,  34,  36,  37,  38,  40],
       [ 51,  52,  54,  56,  57,  58,  60],
       [ 61,  62,  64,  66,  67,  68,  70],
       [ 71,  72,  74,  76,  77,  78,  80],
       [ 91,  92,  94,  96,  97,  98, 100]])]
```

Comment: It will need loop like `for i in range(1, 4): mask[2**i] = 0`

Comment: I mean random numbers...not following any pattern.

Comment: if you want random number then you eventually can put them on list and do `for i in list_of_random_numbers: mask[i] = 0`.

Comment: I mean i know these specific numbers. Here, ```2,4,8``` but could be ```1,3,4``` or ```2,5,6```.

Comment: Try `mask[[2,4,8]] = 0`

Comment: you could put these values in place of `list_of_random_numbers` - `for i in [2,4,8]:` or `for i in [1,3,4]:` or `for i in [2,5,6]:` but comment `mask[[2,4,8]] = 0` can be simpler